# How to scale Histogram counts with the value of bin center?

Tags: plotting, histograms, scaling, logarithmic-scale

I am analyzing some variates from a steeply falling power-law distribution (approximately with a power index -4) using

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

While the option `ScalingFunctions->{"Log", "Log"}` helps a lot in keeping the results in perspective, I cannot really see small deviations from the power law since the dominant trend in the log-log view will be a linear function with approximate slope -4. The usual trick in such studies is to scale the resulting pdf by dividing it with the approximate trend, i.e. for the bin entries I want something like

```
ScalingFunctions->{"Log", Function[{count, center}, Log[center^4 count]]}
```

instead of only `Function[x, Log[x]]` which I get with the `"Log"` option. Unfortunately `Histogram` seems to call this function with only one argument which is the corresponding bin count (or pdf value in my case), unlike e.g. `Plot` which calls `RegionFunction` with all the coordinates and similarly other plotting functions in Mathematica.

Is there a way to convince Mathematica to call the scaling functions not only with the bin value but also with the bin center or location of bin edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nice 3-rd argument in `Histogram`

```
data = RandomReal[1.0, 1000000]^(-1/3);

Histogram[data, 100, #2/(-Subtract @@@ #)/ Total[#2] (Mean /@ #)^4 &,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

Pure `#2/(-Subtract @@@ #)/Total[#2] &` is equivalent to `"PDF"`.

Results are better with log-scaled bins

```
Histogram[data, {"Log", 20}, #2/(-Subtract @@@ #)/Total[#2] (Mean /@ #)^4 &, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

P.S. Why I chose `RandomReal[1.0, 1000000]^(-1/3)` for power-law distribution with a power index -4?

See:

```
PDF@TransformedDistribution[x^(-1/3), x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's it! But is berried really deep down in the documentation...

Comment: @DarkoVeberic A lot of interesting things buried in the Details&Options section :) Note that I correct one mistake and update the answer.

Comment: Can you guess which `fh` function is equivalent to the `"PDF"` option?

Comment: Ah, great, you've answered it while I was typing the question...